# Can't seem to figure out why the script isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to figure out why this div slideshow script isn't working:'

The script:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

The html:

```
<div id="slideshow">
<div>
<img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
</div>
<div>
<img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
</div>
<div>
Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the link to the site:
http://www.pearsonaviation.com.au/new/

Any help would be really appreciated, cheers!

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined `

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the `jQuery` library included on the page.

Hence the sea of error messages.

Go to this page :http://jquery.com/download/ 
 Either download the jQuery js file, host it on your server and reference it in the page, or use one of the CDNs specified on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have allot of errors in console. Slideshow depends on jquery-library, try to include that first.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used noConflict in the page, `$` in global scope does not point to jQuery library. So instead try

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() { 
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  3000);
})
```